# How to hack a Password of Private Key

Tags: blockchain, wallet, security, private-key, private-blockchains

I have a Private key and then after I entered it, there's another saying

> "Input a required Password of Private Key"

So how can I hack or generate that?

Comment: "... and then after i entered it...", what software are you entering it into?

Answer (score 1):

The private key you have is encrypted so to decrypt it you need to have a valid password that's why it is asking for the password. It can't be hacked, you need a correct password